# Get path to R.java file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How do I get the path to the generated R.java file in androids gradle plugin? Are there different R.java file paths for different buildTypes / flavors? I guess it will be stored as an gradle variable. I couldn't find the gradle variable name in in the official docs

So my question is:
How do I get the path to the R.java file in gradle (code)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use modern (gradle) build system then by default it is in `build/generated/source/r/[build flavor/]{release|debug}/{app package}` in your project module source tree. The `build flavor` is optional. If you haven't build flavors, this part is missing.

Any Android library modules (AAR) adds their own `R` classes in the similar directories ending with their package paths.

Comment: i know, but I want to get the variable in gradle for my own gradle plugin

Comment: In the `IncrementalTask` class there is `getSourceOutputDir()` method that seems to be used for getting that path. So probably you can get it if you create your own task class. Sorry, can't say more because I don't write on groovy and never wrote a custom task class.